# Laravel reset password page -> blade view to vueJS page. csrf token problem?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I tried to move all my laravel view to vuejs views. I think they are similar and send the same data, but the vueJS page doesn't work...

email.blade.php is the page for reseting password. I rewrote all the code: it sends an email with a reset password token, I click on the email link.

With the laravel view, it works well.
With the vueJS view, the reset token is invalid. Here is the error: This password reset token is invalid.

[image]

Any idea what is the difference?

**Here is the vueJS view**

```
<template>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent>
                                <input type="hidden" name="token" v-model="token">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{$t('resetPwd.email')}}</label>

                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="email" type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" name="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <p v-if="emailalreadyexists==false" class="error">{{$t('resetPwd.emailDoesntExist')}}</p>
                                <button @click="checkEmailExistsAndSend" class="btn-itra-green-white">
                                    {{$t('resetPwd.sendLink')}}
                                </button>
                                <p v-if="emailsent==true">{{$t('resetPwd.okCheckMails')}}</p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        nom: "login",
        data () {
            return {
                APP_URL: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
                emailsent: false,
                token: '',
                csrf:'',
                emailalreadyexists: true,
                email :''
            }
        },
        mounted()
        {
          this.token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        },
        components: {
            customimagepanel,whitepanel
        },
        methods:{
             checkEmailExistsAndSend(){
                this.emailalreadyexists=true;
                this.emailsent=false;
                if(this.email!=null && this.email!=undefined && this.email.length>5 && this.email.includes('@') )
                {
                    axios.get('/registration/emailexists/' + this.email).then(
                        response => {
                            if(response.data==true){
                                this.emailalreadyexists=true;
                                console.log("emailalreadyexists");
                                this.pwdemail();
                            }
                            else{
                                this.emailalreadyexists=false;
                                console.log("!emailalreadyexists");
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            },
            pwdemail(){
                this.emailsent=true;
                var bodyFormData = new FormData();
                bodyFormData.set('_token', this.token);
                bodyFormData.set('email', this.email);
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/password/email',
                    data: bodyFormData,
                    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Here is the original blade view**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Send Password Reset Link') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up the password reset token with the CSRF token. They are entirely different things, with different values and purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I understand well the CSRF token is the token I send through the form, @csrf in laravel and $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'); with vuejs. Is there a difference between these two?
the password reset token: I don't think I change this one at all, it is processed by laravel... Maybe I missed something here?